# HTML 5 progress bar tag with gradient as background

Tags: css, html, styles, progress-bar, linear-gradients

I want to style a html5 progress bar tag as following:

The bar background itself should be a gradient with a fixed 100% width.
But the gradient should just be visible where the value of the bar is...

> ```
> progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
>   background: linear-gradient(to right, red 1%, green);
> }
> ```

What do I put in the style for the value, or can I do something else?

> ```
>   progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
>     //some code here
>   }
> ```

Or maybe some kind of inverted css masking?

Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: checkout this link https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/ there is an explanation for progress bar styling in it with examples

Comment: thanks, I found that link already but they don't really explain how I can set a gradient I the background which is just shown where the current value-bar is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved it with a workaround.

I rotate the progress bar on the Y axis with:

```
> transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

then, I set the value background the inherited background in order to make it look completely transparent.

Now, last step, in my value calculation I inverted the values. So that a `value="100"` represents an empty progress bar in the DOM and a `value="0"` represent a full (100%) progress bar.